# Python Socket strange IP connection from outside

Tags: python, sockets

A little summary, i programm a socket server in python to fetch data from my MSSQL database and send it to my Flutter App. So far so good. Now i tried to test it from outside. I set a Port Forwarding and tried to connect it. btw it works fine. I let the server run for few hours and now i get a error messenge.
See the pic, the first ip is mine but the second is not.
Someone is trying to connect to my server. How do solve this Problem
[image]

MY Python Code

```
from datetime import datetime
import socket
from SqlServerRequest import SqlServerRequest


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('192.168.43.126', 2222))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established.")
    data = clientsocket.recv(2048).decode()
    print(data)

    if data == "open":
        o = SqlServerRequest.dataForOpenOrders()
        clientsocket.sendall(bytes(o,"utf-8"))
    if data == "closed":
        c = SqlServerRequest.dataForClosedOrders()
        clientsocket.sendall(bytes(c,"utf-8"))

    clientsocket.close()
```

Comment: Port 2222 is a [known port](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=2222), so the packet you received containing the `0xCE` byte, may have been a header request for another service which listens on 2222. This was just a bot on the internet scraping known ports trying to find running services.

Comment: thx, your suggestion is to use ports greater than 49152 ?

Comment: Use any port, but secure your service. You willget scraped by a bot no matter what port you pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you did set up port forwarding to allow anyone on the internet to connect to your machine. Someone just did, and sent something to your program that it didn't expect, and your program crashed.

That's a great lesson on making your program [robust in the face of unexpected input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle), for instance.

Secondly, if you want your program to actually be accessible on the internet, you will probably want some sort of authentication -- for instance, a password known by your Flutter client.

Likely on top of that, you'd want some sort of [transport-layer security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) so people can't read your data in-flight.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, do you have some examples ? I read about SSL but i never use it and i imagine it gonna be difficult between python and flutter to programm a save connection.

Comment: Unless there's a good reason to use bare socket connections, for a request-response sort of server like you seem to have, you might consider just using HTTP and HTTPS instead; you can bet there are HTTP/S libraries for Flutter. Flask or FastAPI (or Starlette) are good frameworks for that.

Comment: in your opinion, a fastapi is more secure than a socket like mine with ssl encryption?

Comment: It's as secure (both are plaintext within TLS), but you'll have an easier time interacting with something standard like HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

The crash happens because you're trying to convert to Unicode.  If this is really all there is, then it's silly to convert to Unicode at all.  Just leave it as a bytes string.

```
wwhile True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established.")
    data = clientsocket.recv(2048)
    print(data)
    if data == b"open":
        o = SqlServerRequest.dataForOpenOrders()
        clientsocket.sendall(bytes(o,"utf-8"))
    if data == b"closed":
        c = SqlServerRequest.dataForClosedOrders()
        clientsocket.sendall(bytes(c,"utf-8"))

    clientsocket.close()
```

Comment: Thanks but no, the code works fine(when my app connect to the server) - someone else tried send something to my server what the server didnt expect

Comment: Yes, I know.  The crash happened because you assumed everything you're going to be receiving is 7-bit ASCII.  The unknown app sent you binary, and you crashed.  My code will eliminate the crash and just let you ignore that data.  So, don't tell me "no".

Comment: No harm meant buddy ... i thought you dont get what my problem is. I will try your solution